# When I click the buttons the screen is not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, web

creating a calculator app in vanilla JavaScript everything was working just fine but when I click the different calculator buttons nothing is being rendered to my screen and I don't get where the problem is  is my JavaScript  code

```
let buffer = "0";
let previousOperator;**strong text**
const screen = document.querySelector(".screen");

function buttonClick(value) {
 if (isNaN(parseInt(value))) {
     handleSymbol(value);
 } else {
     handleNumber(value);
 }
 rerender();
}

function handleNumber(value) {
 if (buffer === "0") {
     buffer = value;
 } else {
     buffer += value;
 }
}

function handleMath(value) {
 if (buffer === "0") {
     // do nothing
     return;
 }

 const intBuffer = parseInt(buffer);
 if (runningTotal === 0) {
     runningTotal = intBuffer;
 } else {
     flushOperation(intBuffer);
 }

 previousOperator = value;

 buffer = "0";
}

function flushOperation(intBuffer) {
 if (previousOperator === "+") {
     runningTotal += intBuffer;
 } else if (previousOperator === "-") {
     runningTotal -= intBuffer;
 } else if (previousOperator === "×") {
     runningTotal *= intBuffer;
 } else {
     runningTotal /= intBuffer;
 }
}

function handleSymbol(value) {
 switch (value) {
     case "C":
         buffer = "0";
         runningTotal = 0;
         break;
     case "=":
         if (previousOperator === null) {
             // need two numbers to do math
             return;
         }
         flushOperation(parseInt(buffer));
         previousOperator = null;
         buffer = +runningTotal;
         runningTotal = 0;
         break;
     case "←":
         if (buffer.length === 1) {
             buffer = "0";
         } else {
             buffer = buffer.substring(0, buffer.length - 1);
         }
         break;
     case "+":
     case "-":
     case "×":
     case "÷":
         handleMath(value);
         break;
 }
}

function rerender() {
 screen.innerText = buffer;
}

function init() {
 document
     .querySelector(".calc-buttons")
     .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
         buttonClick(event.target.innerText);
     });
}

init();
```

when I click my buttons they are not being rendered on the screen as expected even though I have included a rerender() function on the function that handles click events

Comment: `document.querySelector(".calc-buttons").addEventListener` adds an event handler to a single element - not sure why you say plural `buttons` in your question since only one button could possibly have an event listener attached

Comment: @JaromandaX - I think it's an event delegate as I was able to make it work with the calc buttons in a container.

Comment: @HabibaYvonne - Please share your calculator html as that might also be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have several buttons with the same class that's why

Comment: and `document.querySelector` will select ONE

Answer (score 0):

You're using `querySelector` which only ever selects one thing. My guess is that whatever the first button you have with that class is actually working. If not you have other problems. You want to select multiple buttons, so you need `querySelectorAll`. Since that will return multiple buttons, you need to loop through and attach the event handler to all of them as such:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons');
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', event => console.log(event.target.textContent)))
```

See working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/rlouie/yx6sg014/

If this doesn't fix your issue, you've got something else wrong in your code.